# To delete nodes and its relations

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using following query to delete all the nodes and relations:

```
START a=node(2) 
MATCH (a)-[r:PUBLISHED_BY]->(c), 
(b)-[s:PUBLISHED_UNDER]->(c) 
DELETE r,s,c;
```

but I'm getting the following error message.

> ==> TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction

Please help me where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You have to delete all relationships when you delete nodes. Try this one.

```
MATCH (a)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]->(c)
WHERE id(a) = 2
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r]-()
DELETE c, r;
```

Comment: maybe you don't even need the b part of the match.

Comment: Hi,
I used the following query but I'm getting the following exception:
 
START a=node(2) MATCH (a)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]->(c)<-[:PUBLISHED_UNDER]-(b) WITH c MATCH (c)-[r?]-() DELETE c, r;
==> SyntaxException: Question mark is no longer used for optional patterns - use OPTIONAL MATCH instead (line 1, column 88)
==> "START a=node(2) MATCH (a)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]->(c)<-[:PUBLISHED_UNDER]-(b) WITH c MATCH (c)-[r?]-() DELETE c, r"
==>                                                                                         ^

Comment: If you are using 2.0 r? is deprecated. Instead use http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-optional-match.html START a=node(2)
MATCH (a)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]->(c)<-[:PUBLISHED_UNDER]-(b)
WITH c
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r]-()
DELETE c, r;

Comment: I guess it was a bad assumption--guessed by the start clause. :)

Comment: Hi,
I tried the following query, it is working fine in my localhost:

START a=node(3896) MATCH (a)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]->(c)<-[:PUBLISHED_UNDER]-(b), (a)-[:CREATED_BY]->(b) WITH c OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r]-(), (b)-[s]-() DELETE c, r, b, s;

but when I'm running it in my server it is giving the following exception:
SyntaxException: Invalid input 'P': expected 'r/R' (line 1, column 107)

Comment: Also tell me how I'll return some thing on success or on  error

Comment: Hi Luanne,
In my local I'm using Neo4j-2.0.0 and in my server I'm using Neo4j-2.0.0-M05 is there any issue because of that?\
Also tell me how I should return something on success and on error.

Comment: Yes, upgrade your server to Neo4j 2.0.0, the optional match was introduced with 2.0.0-M06

Comment: Thanks Michael, Also tell me how I should return something on success and on error.